# How to loop through an array of images and save each with Active Storage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, rails-activestorage

Rails 5.2 app

I am saving multiple images via a POST from a an XML object sent from a mobile app.

The images look like this when they are received:

```
"image_group"=>
[
  {"report_image"=>"1565721255925.jpg"}, 
  {"report_image"=>"1565721267236.jpg"}, 
  {"report_image"=>"1565721279636.jpg"}, 
  {"report_image"=>"1565721292231.jpg"}
]
```

So, these images belong to a report. I am saving the report with the images in a controller that handles the POST.

I am saving the images to report with the following block:

```
r = Report.new()

  image_arr = record[:image_group]

  image_arr.each do |image|
    r.images.attach(io: File.open("#{params[image[:report_image]].path}"), filename: "#{image[:report_image]}")
  end

r
```

This works when there are 1 or 2 images. However, when I do 3 or more the last report_image does not come with a path.

Here is the error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `path' for nil:NilClass):
```

How do I resolve the issue and save ALL of the images?

Here is the entire output from the rails server. *Some of the labels are changed in the following output. The important thing to see here is that the last image does not have a path.

```
financial_image_arr ======== [{"financial_page_image"=>"1565721255925.jpg"}, {"financial_page_image"=>"1565721267236.jpg"}, {"financial_page_image"=>"1565721279636.jpg"}, {"financial_page_image"=>"1565721292231.jpg"}]
image  ================ {"financial_page_image"=>"1565721255925.jpg"}
path  ================ /var/folders/zp/w8d7c5bs3glbprv_hs22m2k80000gn/T/RackMultipart20190813-79202-sfqs4i.jpg
  Disk Storage (13.7ms) Uploaded file to key: 65GicEnFZ7868efthA3VaZHs (checksum: l+IKb1kWR786TDXTtZPShw==)
   (0.7ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/skooter/odk_controller.rb:255
  ActiveStorage::Blob Create (1.3ms)  INSERT INTO "active_storage_blobs" ("key", "filename", "content_type", "metadata", "byte_size", "checksum", "created_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["key", "65GicEnFZ7868efthA3VaZHs"], ["filename", "1565721255925.jpg"], ["content_type", "image/jpeg"], ["metadata", "{\"identified\":true}"], ["byte_size", 2558086], ["checksum", "l+IKb1kWR786TDXTtZPShw=="], ["created_at", "2019-08-13 20:37:55.864812"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/skooter/odk_controller.rb:255
   (43.7ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/skooter/odk_controller.rb:255
image  ================ {"financial_page_image"=>"1565721267236.jpg"}
path  ================ /var/folders/zp/w8d7c5bs3glbprv_hs22m2k80000gn/T/RackMultipart20190813-79202-1ulro7l.jpg
  Disk Storage (15.3ms) Uploaded file to key: Dc8kVypDbmkKfC9wWiVKrQiP (checksum: ZdzLsDJlDRFcLtdUCTrOng==)
   (0.9ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/skooter/odk_controller.rb:255
  ActiveStorage::Blob Create (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "active_storage_blobs" ("key", "filename", "content_type", "metadata", "byte_size", "checksum", "created_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["key", "Dc8kVypDbmkKfC9wWiVKrQiP"], ["filename", "1565721267236.jpg"], ["content_type", "image/jpeg"], ["metadata", "{\"identified\":true}"], ["byte_size", 3038981], ["checksum", "ZdzLsDJlDRFcLtdUCTrOng=="], ["created_at", "2019-08-13 20:37:55.949371"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/skooter/odk_controller.rb:255
   (41.7ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/skooter/odk_controller.rb:255
image  ================ {"financial_page_image"=>"1565721279636.jpg"}
path  ================ /var/folders/zp/w8d7c5bs3glbprv_hs22m2k80000gn/T/RackMultipart20190813-79202-19wtddw.jpg
  Disk Storage (15.3ms) Uploaded file to key: SXdChJUgv6KP5AimKsi51m1y (checksum: k2vsaTsVXn+P/E7uUNj0wg==)
   (0.7ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/skooter/odk_controller.rb:255
  ActiveStorage::Blob Create (1.2ms)  INSERT INTO "active_storage_blobs" ("key", "filename", "content_type", "metadata", "byte_size", "checksum", "created_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["key", "SXdChJUgv6KP5AimKsi51m1y"], ["filename", "1565721279636.jpg"], ["content_type", "image/jpeg"], ["metadata", "{\"identified\":true}"], ["byte_size", 2931139], ["checksum", "k2vsaTsVXn+P/E7uUNj0wg=="], ["created_at", "2019-08-13 20:37:56.045458"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/skooter/odk_controller.rb:255
   (41.5ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/skooter/odk_controller.rb:255
image  ================ {"financial_page_image"=>"1565721292231.jpg"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 518ms (ActiveRecord: 171.8ms)



NoMethodError (undefined method `path' for nil:NilClass):
```

**UPDATE**

Here is the output when I add:

`puts "params  ================ #{params[image[:financial_page_image]]}"`

```
financial_image_arr ======== [{"financial_page_image"=>"1565733645208.jpg"}, {"financial_page_image"=>"1565733658237.jpg"}, {"financial_page_image"=>"1565733673964.jpg"}, {"financial_page_image"=>"1565733688371.jpg"}]
params  ================ #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007ffca0f4b290>
image  ================ {"financial_page_image"=>"1565733645208.jpg"}
path  ================ /var/folders/zp/w8d7c5bs3glbprv_hs22m2k80000gn/T/RackMultipart20190813-85337-ffz5sv.jpg
params  ================ #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007ffca0f4b218>
image  ================ {"financial_page_image"=>"1565733658237.jpg"}
path  ================ /var/folders/zp/w8d7c5bs3glbprv_hs22m2k80000gn/T/RackMultipart20190813-85337-1fs8j1i.jpg
params  ================
image  ================ {"financial_page_image"=>"1565733673964.jpg"}
```

**Update**

Here is the entire output.
*Some of the labels have changed here, but everything else is the same and in the same order.

```
=======================XML Object=======================
### XML Object: {"has_assignment_card"=>"no", "assignment_name"=>"Pqpqpq", "set_assignment_id"=>"1", "has_organization_card"=>"no", "organization_name"=>"Pqpqpq", "set_organization_id"=>"1", "attendance_page_yes_no"=>"yes", "attendance_page_group"=>[{"attendance_page_image"=>"1565900276910.jpg"}, {"attendance_page_image"=>"1565900288347.jpg"}, {"attendance_page_image"=>"1565900306471.jpg"}], "attendance_data_yes_no"=>"no", "start"=>"2019-08-15T14:17:28.668-06:00", "end"=>"2019-08-15T14:18:32.940-06:00", "today"=>"2019-08-15", "deviceid"=>"353325097059590", "subscriberid"=>"706010493091431", "simserial"=>"8950301218077912618", "username"=>"peru_collector@test.com", "phonenumber"=>nil, "meta"=>{"instanceID"=>"uuid:e291337f-2da5-45e1-8990-c23a1f3adb5e", "instanceName"=>"Activity:  2019-08-15"}, "id"=>"activity", "xmlns:ev"=>"http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events", "xmlns:orx"=>"http://openrosa.org/xforms", "xmlns:xsd"=>"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "xmlns:odk"=>"http://www.opendatakit.org/xforms", "xmlns:jr"=>"http://openrosa.org/javarosa", "xmlns:h"=>"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"}
=======================XML Object=======================
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["email", "peru_collector@test.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/skooter/odk_controller.rb:31
  Program Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "programs".* FROM "programs" WHERE "programs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/skooter/odk_controller.rb:31
image_arr ======== [{"attendance_page_image"=>"1565900276910.jpg"}, {"attendance_page_image"=>"1565900288347.jpg"}, {"attendance_page_image"=>"1565900306471.jpg"}]
puts "params[image[:attendance_page_image]]  ================ #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007faa5bdd5560>
puts "params[image[:attendance_page_image]]  ================ #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007faa5bdd44a8>
puts "params[image[:attendance_page_image]]  ================
  Rendering /Users/jefferson/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/bundler/gems/skooter-5bc83089cbef/app/views/skooter/odk/submissions.xml.erb
  Rendered /Users/jefferson/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/bundler/gems/skooter-5bc83089cbef/app/views/skooter/odk/submissions.xml.erb (0.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 211ms (Views: 33.7ms | ActiveRecord: 11.1ms)
```

So, you can see that the first two images come with params and let me upload using .path, but the last one does not have params. It is nil.

**Update**

Here is the output when I add .inspect to the params:

```
=======================XML Object=======================
### XML Object: {"has_assignment_card"=>"no", "assignment_name"=>"Pqpqpq", "set_assignment_id"=>"1", "has_organization_card"=>"no", "organization_name"=>"Pqpqpq", "set_organization_id"=>"1", "attendance_page_yes_no"=>"yes", "attendance_page_group"=>[{"attendance_page_image"=>"1565900276910.jpg"}, {"attendance_page_image"=>"1565900288347.jpg"}, {"attendance_page_image"=>"1565900306471.jpg"}], "attendance_data_yes_no"=>"no", "start"=>"2019-08-15T14:17:28.668-06:00", "end"=>"2019-08-15T14:18:32.940-06:00", "today"=>"2019-08-15", "deviceid"=>"353325097059590", "subscriberid"=>"706010493091431", "simserial"=>"8950301218077912618", "username"=>"peru_collector@test.com", "phonenumber"=>nil, "meta"=>{"instanceID"=>"uuid:e291337f-2da5-45e1-8990-c23a1f3adb5e", "instanceName"=>"Activity:  2019-08-15"}, "id"=>"activity", "xmlns:ev"=>"http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events", "xmlns:orx"=>"http://openrosa.org/xforms", "xmlns:xsd"=>"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "xmlns:odk"=>"http://www.opendatakit.org/xforms", "xmlns:jr"=>"http://openrosa.org/javarosa", "xmlns:h"=>"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"}
=======================XML Object=======================
  User Load (3.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["email", "peru_collector@test.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/skooter/odk_controller.rb:31
  Program Load (2.0ms)  SELECT  "programs".* FROM "programs" WHERE "programs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/skooter/odk_controller.rb:31
image_arr ======== [{"attendance_page_image"=>"1565900276910.jpg"}, {"attendance_page_image"=>"1565900288347.jpg"}, {"attendance_page_image"=>"1565900306471.jpg"}]
params[image[:attendance_page_image]] ================ #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007faa61f88d20 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/zp/w8d7c5bs3glbprv_hs22m2k80000gn/T/RackMultipart20190815-11949-hqxxbg.jpg>, @original_filename="1565900276910.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"1565900276910.jpg\"; filename=\"1565900276910.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\nContent-Length: 2768335\r\n">
params[image[:attendance_page_image]] ================ #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007faa61f887a8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/zp/w8d7c5bs3glbprv_hs22m2k80000gn/T/RackMultipart20190815-11949-l9mkv.jpg>, @original_filename="1565900288347.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"1565900288347.jpg\"; filename=\"1565900288347.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\nContent-Length: 3848689\r\n">
params[image[:attendance_page_image]] ================ nil
  Rendering /Users/jefferson/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/bundler/gems/skooter-5bc83089cbef/app/views/skooter/odk/submissions.xml.erb
  Rendered /Users/jefferson/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/bundler/gems/skooter-5bc83089cbef/app/views/skooter/odk/submissions.xml.erb (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 277ms (Views: 40.2ms | ActiveRecord: 19.4ms)
```

**Update**

I just reviewed my code and it started working. Here is the block that is working saving all of the images:
I am open to suggestions to improve this.

```
if record[:attendance_page_yes_no].eql?('yes')
  image_arr = record[:attendance_page_group]
  if image_arr.length > 1
    puts "image_arr ======== #{image_arr}"
    image_arr.each do |image|

      #puts "path ================ #{params[image[:attendance_page_image]].inspect}"
      #puts "name ================ #{image[:attendance_page_image]}"

      a.attendance_page_images.attach(io: File.open("#{params[image[:attendance_page_image]].path}"), filename: "#{image[:attendance_page_image]}")

    end if !image_arr.empty?
  else 
    a.attendance_page_images.attach(io: File.open("#{params[record[:attendance_page_group][:attendance_page_image]].path}"), filename: "#{record[:attendance_page_group][:attendance_page_image]}")
  end
end
```

Comment: you're expecting a passed param to be an object that has a path method which is why you're getting the error. `params` is a hash of objects — none of which should respond to `path`.

Comment: You are definitely on to something. I updated my answer. I just added `puts "params etc.` to look at the output and it is just blank on the third element.

Comment: This `params[image[:report_image]]` is difficult to understand, are you trying to access a key on params? wouldn't it be `params[:image][:report_image]`?

Comment: Could you also show the complete output from `params`? 
It's also not easy to follow your log, when you can't see how the log was created.

Comment: For some files, ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile object could not be created. Application gives error because ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile does not exist. The problem seems to be in the file upload phase. Could it be because the file sizes are large?

Comment: I don't have any validations for file size

Comment: Maybe the real question is just how to get the path of the images. If I have the path of the image, then I can run this:
 @message.image.attach(io: File.open('/path/to/file'), filename: 'file.pdf', content_type: 'application/pdf')

Comment: Add your models and controller, all code involved to try to recreate this scenario.

Comment: It definitely seems to be on your form side. I assume that you have a multipart and that images are sent at the same time, and you use the filename as the "name" property. Pardon the question, but why don't you put files under an array input name like `report_images[]`? That way you get an array of temp files which includes their filenames and you don't have to reconcile these from 2 different places. At least you'll see if images are not uploaded because of size or anything. And if your XML carries more info, then fine but don't use it to process the file, only after to add info.

Comment: I'm not saving them with a form. They are coming into the app from a POST method  and request format is XML. The images come in like the first code snippet with "image_group"=>...

Comment: I don't understand why it works for the first two or three images, but then stops and returns nil because an object couldn't be created for the third or fourth image

Comment: It just started working. I just reviewed my code and made sure this line was right: a.attendance_page_images.attach(io: File.open("#{params[image[:attendance_page_image]].path}"), filename: "#{image[:attendance_page_image]}")

Comment: @demir you were right it was the file size. you can answer the question about the file size with your comment. I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` object could not be created for some images. Application gives error because `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` does not exist. The problem seems to be in the file upload phase. Images with a large file size may cause this error.